# How to store data permanently in XML in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can i store data permanently in XML and display that data from the XML?
I can store data temporarily but i want to store and display the data whatever there in XML until we delete that data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save it as a file in [isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). Assuming you're using LINQ to XML, it's easy - just use the isolated storage API to create a stream to read or write, and pass that to the appropriate LINQ to XML methods (`XDocument.Load`, `XDocument.Save` etc).

Comment: I want to store the data permanently in XML.After getting the parsed data i have to store that data and display that data whenever user login

Comment: @SumeshMohanK: Right, so you store the data in isolated storage when you've parsed it, then load it from isolated storage when you log in...

Comment: As a sidenote, I was going to provide a similar answer to this but you beat me to it... note to self... You've got to get up pretty early in the morning to "Beat the Skeet!"

Answer (score 1):

The store the data 'permanently' you will need to write the XML data out to a file, probably storing it in IsolatedStorage.

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{

... 

}
```

Then create a file using the store:

```
var stream = store.OpenFile("mydata.xml");
```

Finally use XDocument.Save(stream, options) to write the XML to the file.

```
doc.Save(stream, SaveOptions.None);
```

Loading will be done in reverse.